# Is it possible to get items from past events?

Tags: motor-world-car-factory

In the video game, Motor World: Car Factory, is it possible to get items from past events you missed? I want to finish my collection of cars.

Comment: Wow, This is so dead, I got the tumbleweed achievement...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but no there is not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Events are cyclical, even though there are some changes from version to version. So the events repeat themselves after a cycle.

For example, the [Catman Origins](http://motorworld.wikia.com/wiki/Catman_Origins) event has already happened nine times. Since the game is celebrating its 4th anniversary, the cycle should be less than six months.